Mosaicking and exporting image collection in Earth Engine
I'm fairly new in Earth Engine so I would love to get another opinion on what I might be doing wrong here. Essentially my code is taking an image collection, mosaicking the images from the same date to account for overlapping pixels, and then reducing them to get the area of several different types of land cover, before exporting the final collection. This seems to work fine, however when I export the images in the collection I seem to lose a lot of the properties of the images which are in the collection, specifically anything related to the date of the image. I readded the system:index based on the position of the image in the collection and the date as an image property in the mosaicking function, and can select and call it just fine in the code. However the date (or anything similar like system:time_start) are not exported along with the pixel data, although all the individual data I need is being exported just fine. I've tried to export any metadata and properties that are date-related alone but I just end up with a blank spreadsheet. I need the dates to be able to construct and visualize time series of the data. I've tried to also manually add the dates in R where I will be working but this is tedious and has its own problems.
For reference, here is the code I've written:
function maskS2clouds(x) {
  var qa = x.select('QA60');

  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  var image = x.updateMask(mask);
  return image;
}

var startDate = '2017-01-01';
var endDate = '2024-01-01';

var s2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED")
  .filterBounds(texel)
  .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 20))
  .sort('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE')
  .map(maskS2clouds);

print('s2 collection:', s2);
print(s2.size());
Map.centerObject(texelpoint, 10);

//Combine images of the same date
function mosaicByDate(imcol){
  // imcol: An image collection
  // returns: An image collection
  var imlist = imcol.toList(imcol.size())

  var unique_dates = imlist.map(function(im){
    return ee.Image(im).date().format("YYYY-MM-dd")
  }).distinct()

  var mosaic_imlist = unique_dates.map(function(d){
    d = ee.Date(d)

    var im = imcol
      .filterDate(d, d.advance(1, "day"))
      .mosaic()

    return im.set(
        "system:time_start", d.millis(), 
        "system:id", d.format("YYYY-MM-dd"),
        'date', d.format("YYYY-MM-dd"))
  })

  return ee.ImageCollection(mosaic_imlist)
}

s2 = mosaicByDate(s2);
print("combined dates:", s2);
var doy = s2.aggregate_array('date');
print(doy);

//Determine polygon area
var pixcount = function(image){
   var area = ee.Image.pixelArea();
   var polypix = area.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(), 
    geometry: texel, 
    scale: 10,
    maxPixels: 1e9
    });
  return image.set('polypix', polypix);
};

s2 = s2.map(pixcount);

var minNDVI = -0.1;
var minNDWI = -0.2;

//Add and determine pixels covered by water
var addndwi = function(image){
  var ndwi = image.normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B8']).rename('NDWI');
  var invndwi = ee.Image.constant(0).subtract(ndwi).rename('invndwi');
  var result = image.addBands(ndwi).addBands(invndwi);
  
  var waterthreshold = 0;
  var water = ndwi.gt(waterthreshold);
  
  var area = ee.Image.pixelArea();
  var waterArea = water.multiply(area).rename('waterArea');
  
  result = result.addBands(waterArea);
  var waterpix = waterArea.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
    geometry: texel,
    scale: 10,
    maxPixels: 1e9
  });
  return result.set('waterpix', waterpix);
};
var s2data = s2.map(addndwi);

//Add and determine pixels covered by veg
var addndvi = function(image){
  //var nir = image.select('B8');
  //var red = image.select('B4');
  
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B8A', 'B4']).rename('NDVI');
  var invndvi = ee.Image.constant(0).subtract(ndvi).rename('invndvi');
  var result = image.addBands(ndvi).addBands(invndvi);
  var vegthreshold = 0.2;
  var veg = ndvi.gt(vegthreshold).and(image.select('NDWI').lt(0));
  //result = result.updateMask(veg);
  
  var area = ee.Image.pixelArea();
  var vegArea = veg.multiply(area).rename('vegArea');
  
  result = result.addBands(vegArea);
  var vegpix = vegArea.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
    geometry: texel,
    scale: 10,
    maxPixels: 1e9
  });
  return result.set('vegpix', vegpix);
  
};

var s2data = s2data.map(addndvi);
print('s2 ndvi:', s2data);

var vegPalette = ['red', 'white', 'green'];
Map.addLayer(s2data.select('NDVI'), {
  min: 0,
  max: 1,
  palette: ['red', 'white', 'green']
}, 'NDVI', false);

//Determine intertidal area
var minwat = s2data.qualityMosaic('invndwi');
var maxwat = s2data.qualityMosaic('NDWI');
var meanwat = s2data.mean();

Map.centerObject(texel);
var visParams = {min: 0, max: 0.3, bands: ['B8', 'B3', 'B2']};

Map.addLayer(minwat, visParams, 'LT composite', false);
Map.addLayer(maxwat, visParams, 'HT composite', false);
Map.addLayer(meanwat, visParams, 'Mean composite', false);

//Classify water
var lowtide = minwat.select('NDWI').gte(0.2);
var hightide = maxwat.select('NDWI').gte(0.2);

Map.addLayer(lowtide, {palette: ['darkgreen', 'lightblue']}, 'low tide', false);
Map.addLayer(hightide, {palette: ['darkgreen', 'lightblue']}, 'high tide', false);

//Calculate low and high percentile NDWI
var indexperc = s2data.select(['NDWI']).reduce(ee.Reducer.percentile([20, 80], ['low', 'high']));
var s2data = s2data.map(function(x){
  //get absolute diff
  var selector = x.select('NDWI').subtract(indexperc).abs();
  //invert so min diff is highest value
  var invsel = ee.Image.constant(1).divide(selector);
  //add inverted diff band to image and rename
  return x.addBands(invsel.rename(['selector low', 'selector high']));
});

var minwat2 = s2data.qualityMosaic('selector low');
var maxwat2 = s2data.qualityMosaic('selector high');

Map.addLayer(minwat2, {
  min: 0,
  max: 0.3,
  bands: ['B8', 'B4', 'B3']
}, 'LT composite 2', false);
Map.addLayer(maxwat2, {
  min: 0,
  max: 0.3,
  bands: ['B8', 'B4', 'B3']
}, 'HT composite 2', false);
print('s2 bands: ', s2data);

//Classify images
var lowtide2 = minwat2.select('NDWI').gte(0.2);
var hightide2 = maxwat2.select('NDWI').gte(0.2);
Map.addLayer(lowtide2, {palette: ['darkgreen', 'lightblue']}, 'Low tide 2', false);
Map.addLayer(hightide2, {palette: ['darkgreen', 'lightblue']}, 'High tide 2', false);

//Combine to get intertidal area
var intertidal = lowtide2.eq(0).and(hightide2.eq(1));
var intertidal = intertidal.updateMask(intertidal);

Map.addLayer(intertidal, {palette: ['red']}, 'Intertidal area', false);

//Mask mean NDWI to get a proxy for time submerged
var subtime = meanwat.select('NDWI').updateMask(intertidal);
var visParams = {min: -0.1, max: 0.4, palette: ['red', 'yellow', 'blue']};
Map.addLayer(subtime, visParams, 'Submerged time', false);

Map.addLayer(s2data.select('NDWI'), {
  min: -0.5,
  max: 1,
  palette: ['white', 'blue']
}, 'NDWI', false);

var clipimage = function(image){
  return image.clip(texel);
};


//Detect all pixels that meet the defined conditions 
var algaefunction = function(x){
  // //get pixels above the threshold
  // var NDVI = image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename('NDVI');
  // var NDWI = image.normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B8']).rename('NDWI');
  var algae = x.select('NDVI').gt(0.2).and(x.select('NDWI').lt(0.2));
  //mask those pixels from the image
  //var image = x.updateMask(algae);
//Calculate the area covered by the pixels
  var area = ee.Image.pixelArea();
  var algaeArea = algae.multiply(area).rename('algaeArea');

  x = x.addBands(algaeArea);

  var stats = algaeArea.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(), 
    geometry: texel, 
    scale: 10,
    maxPixels: 1e9
  });

  return x.set(stats);
};

var collection = s2data.map(algaefunction); 

//Determine area of leftover pixels
var barepixels = function(image){
var vegthreshold = 0.2;
var waterthreshold = 0;
var bare = image.select('NDVI').lt(vegthreshold).and(image.select('NDWI').lt(waterthreshold));

  var area = ee.Image.pixelArea();
  var bareArea = bare.multiply(area).rename('bareArea');
  
  var result = image.addBands(bareArea);
  var barepix = bareArea.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
    geometry: texel,
    scale: 10,
    maxPixels: 1e9
  });
  return result.set('barepix', barepix);
};
collection = collection.map(barepixels);
    var t = collection.first();
    print(t.get("date"));
    print(ee.Date(t.get('system:time_start')));

//Collect data to feature
var samplefunc = function(image){
  return image.sample({
    region: texel,
    scale: 30
  });
};
//Divide collection into years    
var firstdate = '2018-01-01';
var lastdate = '2018-12-31';

var newcol = collection.filterDate(firstdate, lastdate)
  .map(samplefunc)
  .flatten();
//print(newcol.limit(10));
var chart = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion(
  collection, texel, ee.Reducer.sum(), 'algaeArea',10)
  .setChartType('ScatterChart')
  .setOptions({
  title: "Macroalgae area at Texel",
  vAxis: {title: 'Area in m2'},
  pointSize:4,
  lineWidth:1,
});

print(chart); 

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: newcol, 
  description: "TexelsmallMerged18",
  folder: "UUThesisData",
  selectors: ["system:index", "system:time_start", "system:id", "date", "algaeArea", "NDVI", "vegArea", "NDWI", "waterArea", "bareArea"]
});

